# NDSolve producing message Power::infy

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, warning-messages, nonlinear

I am trying to solve geodesic equations in some 3D black hole spacetime. It is a coupled ODE system with boundary conditions. Due to the symmetry of the spacetime, I expect the solutions to be even functions, with `r'[0] == 0` and `v'[0] == 0`.

Here's my code:

```
f[r_, v_] := r^2 - 1/2 Tanh[v] - 1/2

NDSolve[
  {0 == D[(r[x]^2 + 2 r'[x] v'[x] - f[r[x], v[x]] v'[x]^2)/r[x]^4, x], 
   r[x]^2 - r[x]^2 v'[x]^2 - r[x] v''[x] + 2 v'[x] r'[x] == 0, 
   r[-1.5] == 100, r[1.5] == 100, v[-1.5] == 10, v[1.5] == 10}, 
  {r, v}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}]
```

But I don't get results, but only the following messages:

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
>   Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.
>   Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity ComplexInfinity encountered.
>   Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered.

Can someone point out what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Probably, an trial solution passes through `r == 0` as `NDSolve` attempts to match the boundary conditions.  Qualitatively, what do you expect the solutions to look like?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I expect r[x] start to decrease at x=-1.5 monotonically to some positive value at r[0] and this is its minimum, then it goes back. v[x] first goes up monotonically to maximum v[0] and then goes down. They are all even functions.

Comment: Do any constants of motion exist?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very sensitive to initial conditions.  Here, we take advantage of the symmetry described in the question to integrate from `x == 0`.

```
s = NDSolveValue[{0 == D[(r[x]^2 + 2 r'[x] v'[x] - f[r[x], v[x]] v'[x]^2)/r[x]^4, x], 
    r[x]^2 - r[x]^2 v'[x]^2 - r[x] v''[x] + 2 v'[x] r'[x] == 0, 
    r[1.5] == 100, r'[0] == 0, v[1.5] == 10, v'[0] == 0}, {r, v}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
        {r[0] == 1.10478, v[0] == 8.5}}]
Row[Plot[#, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> All] &
    /@ Through[s[x]]]
```

[image]

Because `r` varies so rapidly near the endpoints, I reran the calculation with `WorkingPrecision -> 30`.  Results are more precise but otherwise unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of solutions in this model (maybe more). One indicated the author and found bbgodfrey. I will show the second solution, apparently connected with the fall to the center

```
f[r_, v_] := r^2 - 1/2 Tanh[v] - 1/2

plot[a_, b_, x1_] := 
 Block[{A = a, B = b, x0 = 10^-6, xm = x1}, 
  sol = NDSolve[{A^2 == (r[x]^2 + 2 r'[x] v'[x] - 
         f[r[x], v[x]] v'[x]^2)/r[x]^4, 
     r[x]^2 - r[x]^2 v'[x]^2 - r[x] v''[x] + 2 v'[x] r'[x] == 0, 
     r[x0] == 1/A, v'[x0] == 2*x0/A, v[x0] == B}, {r, v}, {x, 0, xm}, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 20, MaxSteps -> 10^6]; {Plot[
    Evaluate[r[x] /. First[sol]], {x, x0, xm}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "r"}], 
   Plot[Evaluate[v[x] /. First[sol]], {x, x0, xm}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "v"}]}]
```

Solution of the first type

```
plot[1001/1000, 1, 1990/1000]
```

Second type solution

```
plot[11/10, 1, 1990/100]
```

[image: fig1]